# Story from the 70's/80's about silver discs that allowed jumping dimensions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The protagonist was a bullied teen with a Vietnamese girlfriend. They find silver coin sized discs that, when pressed, allow the holder to change dimensions. Some of the dimensions were just weird, some were horrible. The ending, if I remember correctly, had the bullies transported to some awful dimension.

I think that this was in a monthly magazine (*Asimov's*?).

Comment: How big were the discs?  Small enough to put in a pocket?  Large enough to stand on?

Comment: Coin sized. Question updated.

Comment: What kind of bullying was it?  Where did they find the coins?  What country was it set in?  What time period was it set in?  What specific dimensions do you remember?  What was weird or horrible about them?  What dimension did the bullies end up in?

Comment: The bullying was pretty standard kid stuff. Nothing memorable. The coins were in the girlfriend's grandfather's house, if I remember correctly. I can't honestly recall any specific dimensions in detail.